# EntityDataSource filtered by Selectedrow of a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, entitydatasource

If I have 2 entities that share a navigation property (In my case an entity called Groups and one called Requirements) and I have a Gridview that displays Groups and another Gridview that I want to display the Requirements in the navigation property of the selected Group, should I pull in all the Requirements in the Requirements DataSource and then filter in the Gridview or should I filter in the DataSource?

I tried filtering in the Requirements DataSource by doing some Linq in the OnQueryCreated event, but I realized that OnQueryCreated is called when the page is loaded and then not again. Is there another event I should use?

Basically: Should I filter in the DataSource and if so where? If I should filter somewhere else, where?